# Does sine interact equationally with addition alone?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, universal-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator\Eq{Eq}\DeclareMathOperator\Th{Th}$*Originally [asked at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164632/does-sine-equationally-interact-with-addition-or-with-multiplication) without success:*

For a structure $\mathcal{A}$ whose signature only contains function and constant symbols, let $\Eq(\mathcal{A})$ be the equational theory of $\mathcal{A}$ — that is, the set of all universal closures of atomic formulas which are satisfied by $\mathcal{A}$. Via trigonometric identities like the double angle identity, [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4164504/28111) that $\Eq(\mathbb{R};+,\times,\sin)$ does *not* "reduce" to $\Eq(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$; formally, we have $\Eq(\mathbb{R};+,\times)\not\models \Eq(\mathbb{R};+,\times,\sin)$.

Notably, all such examples I know crucially involve all three operations available. I'm curious whether this is necessary. Since this question seems harder than I originally suspected, I'll focus on addition specifically:

> Does $\Eq(\mathbb{R};+)\models \Eq(\mathbb{R};+,\sin)$?

I suspect that the answer is **yes**; in a sense this would amount to saying that trigonometric identities have to use multiple arithmetic operations, which matches at least my experience. However, I don't see how to prove this.

Note that $\Eq(\mathcal{A})$ is generally *far* less informative than $\Th(\mathcal{A})$. For example, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is "sufficiently wild." Then $\Th(\mathbb{R};f)$ will be nontrivial (e.g. it will say "$f$ is not injective") but no nontrivial equation will hold in $(\mathbb{R};f)$ so $\emptyset\models \Eq(\mathbb{R};f)$. So the relative tameness of $(\mathbb{R};+)$ from the "coarse" perspective of first-order logic can't help us here.

Comment: Is the question equivalent to asking whether $\sin $ only obeys trivial identities in the language with $+$, that is, only identities that every unary function would obey?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, that's right.

Comment: Do you have counterexamples if we allow constants, such as $\pi$? Can we at least have $1$?

Comment: Isn't it rather that every identity follows from identities satisfied by $+$ in the reals? (would it be equivalent to: every identity $J(\sharp,u)$ such that $J(+,\sin)$ holds in the reals, is such that $J(+,f)$ holds for every self-map $f$ of the reals?

Comment: @YCor I assume(d) Joel was folding in $+$ as you do. For full clarity: it's equivalent to asking whether every equation holding in $(\mathbb{R};+,\sin)$ also holds in $(\mathbb{R};+,f)$ for every unary function $f$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I had meant. So to refute the claim, it would suffice to exhibit a nontrivial identity satisfied by $\sin$ with $+$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Re: your second question, no I don't (besides trivial observations such as "If we include $\pi$ as a constant we get the nontrivial equation $\sin(\pi)+\sin(\pi)=\sin(\pi)$").

Comment: Ah, of course. But I do want $1$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there an obvious reason that allowing $-$ (minus sign) doesn't change the question?

Comment: Do we know any nontrivial rational values of $\sin$ at rational input values? That might  seem likely to lead to a counterexample, right? Or perhaps this never happens?

Comment: @YCor Because $\sin(0)=0$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$, it seems that the answer becomes negative as soon as we include zero or negation.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins [That never happens](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299124/is-sinx-necessarily-irrational-where-x-is-rational).

Comment: Oh dear, I don't know anything.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I mean, I had to google it :P.

Comment: Do you know the answer to your question with “sin” replaced by “exp”? If not, it might be more natural to ask this (first). In any case, your question (at least with “sin” replaced by “exp”) seems strongly related to Schanuel's conjecture, which suggests it would be *way* out of reach of current techniques.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I'm not sure how much I buy the connection with Schanuel. Do you see, for example, a way to resolve the exp-version of the question assuming Schanuel? I don't at a glance.

Comment: It feels to me that the main result of [Trigonometric diophantine equations](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa30/aa3033.pdf) by Conway and Jones should be relevant. I don't quite see how to connect all the dots, but it feels to me that we should be able to start with an alleged identity involving sin and chase through something like the Conway-Jones algorithm to arrive at an identity without sin.

Comment: @TimothyChow Ooh, that's a neat paper, thanks for pointing me towards it! (I also get the feeling that this should help give a positive answer to the question, and I also don't actually see how to do it.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, I think this has a positive answer when $\sin$ is replaced by $\exp$. Suppose $t,u$ are terms in $L(+,\exp)$. Then we say $t<u$ iff $Qx_1 \ldots Qx_n t<u$ in the reals, where $Q$ means “for all sufficiently large”, and $x_1, \ldots x_n$ are the primitive variables in the language. The decision procedure for $t<u$ should be straightforward, and when neither $t<u$ nor $t>u$, it should be easy to prove $t=u$ from the rearrangements justified by $Th(+)$.

Comment: Is it implied that subtraction is also included? If so, you get that sin(x-x) = y-y.

Comment: @PyRulez, no, subtraction is excluded.

Comment: @MattF.  I wonder if that argument can't be slightly modified to work for sine. Since $\sin(z)$ is an analytic function, equality over $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to equality over $\mathbb{C}$. Now, rather than using "sufficiently large" one can use "on a circle, centered at the origin, in the complex plane, with sufficiently large radius", and compare the maximum of the absolute values of the two terms.

Comment: @PaceNielsen, yes, I am writing that up now....

Comment: @MattF.'s [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/395407) referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395315/does-sine-interact-equationally-with-addition-alone#comment1012072_395315).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the outline of a proof that $Eq(\mathbb{R},+)$ proves all the equalities in both $Eq(\mathbb{R},+,\sin)$ and $Eq(\mathbb{R},+,\exp)$.

**Step 1, defining $<$:**

For any term $t$ in $L(+,\sin)$, define a real function $t_R$ by $$t_R(r_1,\ldots r_n)=\sup(\{|t(z_1,\ldots,z_n)|: z_1,\ldots,z_n \in \mathbb{C}, |z_1|=r_1, \cdots, |z_n|=r_n\})$$

Then for terms $t$ and $u$ in $L(+,\sin)$, define $t<u$ iff
$$\mathbb{R}\models Qr_1 \ldots Qr_n\, t_R<u_R$$
where $Q$ is the quantifier "for all sufficiently large" and $n$ is the largest index of a primitive variable which appears in $t+u$.

Similary, for terms $t$ and $u$ in $L(+,\exp)$, define $t<u$ iff
$$\mathbb{R}\models Qx_1 \ldots Qx_n\, t<u$$

**Step 2, determining $<$:**

I claim that for the definitions above:

- $t<x_i$ iff all the primitive variables appearing in $t$ have indices less than $i$.
- $\sin(t)<\sin(u)$ iff $t<u$
- $\exp(t)<\exp(u)$ iff $t<u$
- if $m>1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^m t_i<\sin(u)$ iff $t_i < \sin(u)$ for all $i\le m$.
- if $m>1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^m t_i<\exp(u)$ iff $t_i < \exp(u)$ for all $i\le m$.
- if $m\ge 1$, $n>1$ with $t_1 \ge \cdots \ge t_m$ and $u_1 \ge \cdots \ge u_n$, and none of the $t$'s and $u$'s are sums, then $\sum_{i=1}^m t_i<\sum_{j=1}^n u_j$ iff either $t_k < u_k$ at the first index $k$ where the $t$'s and $u$'s differ, or $m<n$ and $t_k=u_k$ for all $k\le m$.

Furthermore, this provides a recursive algorithm for determining whether $t<u$ for any terms $t$ and $u$ in the same one of the languages above.

**Step 3, normalizing $<$:**

For any term $t$ in the language, we get a normal form $N(t)$ by repeatedly applying the following rules:

- if $a<b$, replace $a+b \rightarrow b+a$
- if $a<b$, replace $a+(b+c) \rightarrow b+(a+c)$
- always replace $(a+b)+c \rightarrow a+(b+c)$

I claim that $t<u$ iff $N(t)$ is smaller than $N(u)$ in the first part that differs.

Now, lexicographically, for any terms $t$ and $u$, either $N(t)<N(u)$ or $N(t)=N(u)$ or $N(t)>N(u)$. In the first and last cases, $t$ and $u$ are not equal over $\mathbb{R}$; for $\sin$ the definition of $<$ tells us that they are different over $\mathbb{C}$, and then the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) tells us that they are also different over $\mathbb{R}$. In the middle case, $Eq(\mathbb{R},+)$ is enough to establish $t=N(t)=N(u)=u$.

Comment: A related [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395315/does-sine-interact-equationally-with-addition-alone#comment1012071_395315) by @PaceNielsen.